# Difference between ラジオ and 無線?

Tags: word-choice, nuances, usage

I've seen both used fairly often, but I've unsure if there's a difference in nuance/usage. Is 無線 more like an actual radio and ラジオ more like a car's radio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

無線 means "wireless" (lit., "no wire/line").  ラジオ simply means "radio".  So in regards to wireless/radio communication, there is no difference.

> 無線通信 = ラジオ通信

But when referencing "radio" as an actual device or media platform, you cannot replace ラジオ with 無線.  For example:

> - I bought a new radio yesterday　→　○ ラジオ　× 無線
> - I enjoy listening to the radio　→　○ ラジオ　× 無線